# How to force Pandas to read numbers as "int64" instead of "float64"

Tags: python, pandas, numbers, int, nan

I have an issue where all of the legacy code I have written no longer works.

I have pandas reading an Excel file, and instead of reading as int64, it now reads as float64.  It is an issue because I cannot perform .merge or .isin on different data type.  I know I can use df.blah.astype(int), but that is very inconvenient to refactor and seems like it should not be necessary.

I am not sure what has caused this.  I am working on a new build of Windows 10, Python 3.5, and Pandas 18.1.  All that changed was an upgrade from Windows 7 and Pandas 18.0.

Was there any change to Pandas?  I cannot find any change in the release notes.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in problematic column between `int` values are some `NaN`. So `pandas` automatically convert `int` to `float`.

[Na type promotions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions).

You can check values by [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,np.nan],
                   'B':[4,5,6]})

print (df)
     A  B
0  1.0  4
1  2.0  5
2  NaN  6

print (df[df.A.isnull()])
    A  B
2 NaN  6
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the Na type promotions.  I can see now that is the issue is related to Na mixed into my int64 columns.